# How do you compare variable types in assembly?

Tags: assembly, macros, masm

This might be a bit of a stupid syntax question, but is there a way you can make conditional jumps based on variable type? I'm trying to write a macro (for a class) that can take a byte, word, or double word as an argument and write it to the screen.

```
mWriteInt MACRO integer:REQ
  ;cmp integer, DWORD 
  ;je dwordOp
    movsx eax, word ptr integer
    call WriteInt
    mov edx, OFFSET endl 
    call WriteString
; for a DWORD
; dwordOp:
ENDM
```

So basically, the code executed should be different based on what type of variable is passed to the macro. No matter how I try to execute this, I get compiler errors.

I've tried:

```
 cmp integer, DWORD
 cmp TYPE integer, DWORD
```

and I don't really know where to go from here. I've looked in every reference I can think of, but it doesn't seem to be a common thing

Edit:

```
mWriteInt MACRO integer:REQ
    IF (TYPE integer EQ TYPE DWORD)
        call WriteInt
    ENDIF

    IF (TYPE integer EQ TYPE BYTE)
        call WriteInt 
    ENDIF

    IF (TYPE integer EQ TYPE WORD)
        movsx eax, word ptr integer
        call WriteInt
    ENDIF

        mov edx, OFFSET endl
        call WriteString
ENDM
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally use a CPU instruction do the comparison, you'd use a directive like IF.

Comment: IF directives in MASM don't work like if statements in C. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bd8b239.aspx

Comment: Okay, something I should have googled before posting lol. I tried again, no errors and it runs, but it doesn't seem to be working. no matter what type I pass, the code never seems to execute

Comment: Think about the instruction you were hoping your macro would generate: `cmp immediate, immediate`.  There is no such encoding, because that would be a useless instruction.  Anyway, now that you've got past that brain-fart, you should post your answer as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the input, but I don't quite understand what you mean by immediate, immediate ? Also I posted as an edit, because the code is still not executing the way it is intended to, but if I should have posted it as an answer I apologize

Comment: It wasn't clear that the edit wasn't a solution.  It looks like the right idea (using assembler conditionals to only assemble the desired instructions), but I don't know MASM syntax.

Comment: Immediates are data embedded in an instruction's machine-code encoding.  e.g. `add edx, 4` uses the `add r32, imm8` encoding (3 bytes: opcode, mod/rm byte, 0x4).  `add edx, eax` uses `add r32, r/m32`, which is a different opcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MASM there is the `OPATTR` operator. Quoted from [the MASM reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2941zhb0.aspx):

> Returns a word defining the mode and scope of expression. The low byte is identical to the byte returned by .TYPE. The high byte contains additional information.

The values are as follows, taken from the `MASM Basic` source code referenced [here at the MASM forum](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=4722.msg51032#msg51032):

```
;     OPATTR guide
;     Bit    Set If...
;     0      References a code label
;     1      Is a memory expression or has a relocatable data label
;     2      Is an immediate expression
;     3      Uses direct memory addressing, i.e. is an absolute memory reference
;     4      Is a register expression
;     5      References no undefined symbols and is without error
;     6      References a stack location (usually a LOCAL variable or parameter)
;     7      References an external label
;     8-10   Language type (000=no type)
;            000 - no language type
;            001 - C/C++ language type
;            010 - SYSCALL language type
;            011 - STDCALL language type
;            100 - Pascal language type
;            101 - FORTRAN language type
;            110 - BASIC language type
```

There are mentioned some examples of usage:

```
atMemory      = 34      ; 00100010      ; [edx+20], [ebx+20], [eax+edx+20], JWasm: [eax+4*eax+20], [eax+20]
atImmediate   = 36      ; 00100100
atLabel       = 37      ; 10100101
atOffset      = 38      ; 10100110      ; offset CrLf$ (immediate and mem expression)
atGlobal      = 42      ; 10101010      ; CrLf$, Masm: [eax+4*eax+20], [eax+20]
atRegLabel    = 43      ; 10101011      ; Masm: [eax+start] (Jwasm yields 37)
atRegister    = 48      ; 00110000      ; also xmm
atXmm         = 77      ; xxxxxxxx      ; reg starting with x
atLocal       = 98      ; 01100010      ; [esp+20], [ebp+20]
```

An example for your MACRO code would be

```
mWriteInt MACRO integer:REQ
  IF(OPATTR(integer) EQ 24h AND SIZEOF(integer) EQ 4)    ; immediate and no undefined symbols
    ; for a DWORD
    mov eax, dword ptr integer
    call WriteInt
  ELSEIF (OPATTR(integer) EQ 24h AND SIZEOF(integer) EQ 2)    ; immediate and no undefined symbols
    ; for a WORD
    movsx eax, word ptr integer
    call WriteInt
  ELSEIF (OPATTR(integer) EQ 24h AND SIZEOF(integer) EQ 1)    ; immediate and no undefined symbols
    ; for a BYTE
    movsx eax, byte ptr integer
    call WriteInt
  ENDIF
  mov edx, OFFSET endl 
  call WriteString
ENDM
```

If this MACRO code is not exactly what you expect, you can adjust the `OPATTR` value by combining the bit values.

One thing to add to describe the difference in MASM between the two variants of IFs:

```
IF   --- is compile time comparison  
.IF  --- is runtime comparison
```

Comment: wow, that is such an incredibly thorough answer. What you're saying makes sense to me, but when I add even your code exactly I get the same result (only the endl BYTE prints). Can there be something wrong with the way I'm passing it? I'm calling : mWriteInt [edi] , which works perfectly well when there are no if statements in the code

Comment: This may be the root of the error: you're calling `mWriteInt [edi]`. `[edi]` has an unspecified size - it is a shortcut for either `dword ptr [edi]`, `word ptr [edi]` or `byte ptr [edi]`. You are probably used to this shortcut, because `mov al, [edi]` infers BYTE size and `mov eax, [edi]` infers DWORD size, respectively. But if you want to distinguish by size in your MACRO you _have to_ specify the size, because otherwise all possibilities would match and so no decision could be made by OPATTR.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're awesome!! That completely solved my problem